# jQuery - After number of elements add html!

Tags: jquery

I need to know if I can count the elements inside a div and after 3 elements to add an html object.

```
<div id="wrapper">
<a href="#">1</a>
<a href="#">1</a>
<a href="#">1</a>
//insert html with jQuery here
<a href="#">1</a>
<a href="#">1</a>
<a href="#">1</a>
//insert html with jQuery here
<a href="#">1</a>
<a href="#">1</a>
<a href="#">1</a>
//insert html with jQuery here
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$('#wrapper a').each(function(i,e){
  if (((i+1) % 3) == 0)
    $(this).after('<p>Hello, world.</p>');
});
```

Take advantage of `.each`'s "i" parameter that gives you element index. Than you can use Modulo to get the 3rd item and append.

Working example: http://www.jsfiddle.net/hd7FP/1/

*at this point just showing an alternative solution*

Comment: @Sshybovycha: Try it out on the jsfiddle link and see if that works. (Trial and error is a very valid way of learning. ;D) - @FlorescuAdrian: You're very welcome.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at the [nth-child-selector](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/).

Basically:

```
$("#wrapper a:nth-child(3n)").after("<span>I'm new.</span>");
```

Comment: I guess he'd need to use .after() instead of append to insert html at those locations.

Comment: This is good, thank you! But it ads the span in the child, not after it. is there any way for me to add the html after the ahref ends?

Comment: @Florescu: You'll want [`after`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) instead of [`append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

Comment: Corrected. Just use `after` instead of `append`.

Comment: .after() it`s good, but it only adds to the first match, not from 3 to 3.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#wrapper a').each(function(index) {
  if ((index+ 1) % 3 == 0)
     $(this).after(content);
});
```